# Kedro airflow on spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, kedro

Looking for kedro+ airflow implementation on spark. Is the plugin now available for spark ?

Looked at PipelineX but couldn't find relevant examples on spark ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't prepared or seen an example to use Spark with PipelineX or Airflow, but it should be possible to use kedro-airflow to run tasks on Spark.

The following document and DataEngineerOne's video might be helpful.

https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/10_tools_integration/01_pyspark.html?highlight=Spark

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYBMpPZep6E